# Keycloak provider configuration: build vs. start

Tags: keycloak

I am configuring an SPI provider (specifically, for the `x509cert-lookup` SPI) in Keycloak, deployed on bare metal. The [provider config documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-provider) tells me to use the `build` command for selecting the provider and the `start` command to pass options to that provider.

However, from [the docs about general configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration) I conclude that all options can also be passed in a `keycloak.conf` file, and the build step is merely an optimization.

If I do not care much about optimizing startup time: Can the build step be eliminated altogether, putting all options into the config file for simplicity? Or is there anything so special about the providers that they must be set in the build step?

(Background: I am running a non-containerized bare metal setup where Keycloak is managed by systemd, and we've had situations where provider configuration was somehow lost between restarts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right when you mention that the extra build step prior to the start command is purely optimization.
In fact, when you call start, it performs a build!

When running inside a containerized environment, the optimization step is a nice feature. Here's the configs that can be set in the extra build step (if desired)
https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?f=build

**If it's not the case**, like you, and you run on bare metal, then the additional build doesn't provide you much.

Here's the most useful link to get you started:
https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration

**Beware** that there is an order of precedence when setting the config such as:

1. command-line parameters
2. environment variables
3. user-created .conf file
4. keycloak.conf file located in the conf directory.

> command-line parameters take precedence over environment (and so on).

Hope this helps!